# Who vs. Whom which is Ok?

Tags: who-whom

Can we say:

- Whom do you call friend?

Or better it would be:

- Who do you call friend?

Which is grammatically fine?

Another questionable is:

- Whom do you vote for?

Or

- Who do you vote for?

Answer (score 1):

Whom is only used as the object of a verb or of a preposition.

So, it'd be:

- Who do you call "friend"?
- Whom do you vote for?

Comment: Yes, *whom* is used for objects...but "You call ___ friend" is also an example of an object, and not a subject, so "Whom do you call friend?" is correct.  That said, we should note that a lot of English speakers have given up on *whom* entirely.

Comment: @stangdon Yes. *Whom* is now mostly a marker of high formality, and should be avoided unless a highly formal tone is desired.